# C# GemBox How to get the position of a TextBox or Shape

Tags: c#, ms-word, gembox-document

I was wondering how I can get the position of a TextBox or a Shape inside the GemBox DLL.

This is my TextBox:

```
var textBox1 = new TextBox(document, Layout.Floating(
    new HorizontalPosition(15, LengthUnit.Pixel, HorizontalPositionAnchor.TopLeftCorner),
    new VerticalPosition(70, LengthUnit.Pixel, VerticalPositionAnchor.TopLeftCorner),
    new Size(pageSetup.PageWidth - 175, 100, LengthUnit.Point)),
    ShapeType.RoundedRectangle);

textBox1.AdjustValues["adj"] = 5000;
textBox1.Outline.Fill.SetEmpty();
textBox1.Fill.SetSolid(Color.White);
```

Now I want to get access to the Horizontal and Vertical position.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
if (textBox1.Layout.IsFloating)
{
    var layout = (FloatingLayout)textBox1.Layout;
    var horizontalPosition = layout.HorizontalPosition;
    var verticalPosition = layout.VerticalPosition;
    // ...
}
```